# get returns a value of the superclass ArrayList in hazelcast 3.5

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast

I have a serialization problem with hazelcast 3.5:

When one hazelcast client(Java) puts a value of class

```
public class MyType extends ArrayList<MyElem>
```

into a map, and afterwards another client (other Java process) retrieves the value,
it gets back a value of class `ArrayList`, not the expected subclass `MyType`!

In hazelcast version 3.1.3 this worked fine: the second client retrieved a value
of the correct subclass `MyType`.

I used the sample configuration hazelcast.xml and the start script server.bat
in both hazelcast versions.

Is this possibly a bug in the new 3.5 version?

My client configuration is *empty*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast (I guess it was) 3.4 added a specialized serializer for List subclasses. You have to register a custom serializer to pick up your type. You can subclass the Hazelcast internal serializer and just exchange the factory and type ids you make it uniquely identified.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but this seems to be a workaround, isn't it?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a bug, therefore it is not considered a workaround :)

Comment: In my universe, after pouring wine into a glass, I don't expect the taste of water when drinking it ;-)

But to be serious: do you know a way to completely switch off this weird new implementation of list serialization? In my opinion it clearly is a design bug.
If this is not possible: as I am not quite familiar with hazelcast classes and internals, do you know where to find sample code for your suggested solution?

Comment: As I said the desired solution is to write your own serializer and register it, together with your custom type, before startup. The reason why this special serializer exists in the first place is that (Identified)DataSerializable and Portable implementing classes are not Serializable and therefore a List serialization would fail (obviously) with a NotSerializableException.

Comment: It's really a pity, because some other Java caching products do not need custom code just for the task of serialization of simple list subclasses.
But it seems there is no other way Hazelcast, so I will try it.
Do you have experience with it, is such a custom serializer difficult to implement?
Can you please give me any hint, perhaps a link, or a code fragment?
Thanks again - for being patient :-)

Comment: You need a hook + serializer (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/nio/serialization/serializers/ArrayListSerializerHook.java ) and you want auto-registration as in (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.SerializerHook )

Comment: This seems to be practicable - thank you for the links :-)
In the meantime, I found another solution: to use a kind of copy constructor after the "get":

public MyType(Collection<MyElem> entries) {
    super(entries);
}

myType = new MyType((Collection<MyElem>)map.get(key));

Comment: @noctarius, Could you please expand on what do you mean by "(Identified)DataSerializable and Portable implementing classes are not Serializable " and second part " herefore a List serialization would fail (obviously) with a NotSerializableException "? what is their relationship with a derivative of ArrayList ?