# Need for custom serializers while using derivatives of ArrayList as value in Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, distributed-caching, distributed-cache, hazelcast-imap

I have an IMAP whose key is a `String` and value is a  derivative of `ArrayList`. I need to run `EntryProcessor` on a key of this map. Also note that `Employee` is a POJO which implements `Serializable` interface.

When I executed the code given below, the code prints "Why so !" and I got `ClassCastException` which mentioned that `java.util.ArrayList` cannot be cast to `Employees` in the `process()` method of `ListValueEntryProcessor` given below.

Q1. I learnt that I need to add custom serializer for my type (`Employees`) so that it could be serialized as `Employees` object and not as `ArrayList` object. I would like to know why is it mandatory to add a "custom serializer" for a built-in type like an `ArrayList` whose items are also marked `Serializable` ?

```
public class Employees extends ArrayList implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   /**
   Constructs a new employees object
   */
   public Employees()
   {
      super();
   }
}

HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = HazelcastHelper.getHazelcastInstance();
IMap<String, Employees> empMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("employeesMap");

Employees empList = new Employees();
Employee employee = new Employee();
empList.add(employee);
empMap.put("companyId", employees);
empMap.executeOnKey("companyId", new IncSalaryEntryProcessor()); 

public static class ListValueEntryProcessor extends AbstractEntryProcessor<String, Employees>
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object process(Entry<String, Employees> arg0) 
    {
        if(! (arg0.getValue() instanceof Employees))
        {
            System.out.println("Why so !");
        }
        // ClassCastException thrown here.
        Employees empList = arg0.getValue();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, I'm certain that I have used `java.util.ArrayList`. There is a related question which validates my understanding. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537670/get-returns-a-value-of-the-superclass-arraylist-in-hazelcast-3-5

Comment: can you post stack trace ?

Comment: @Sam, Exception happens at line `Employees empList = arg0.getValue();`. This is a known case with hazelcast see the SO link I posted above.

Comment: does the code print _Why so_?

Comment: @Sam, yes. it does. To add, `arg0.getValue() instanceof ArrayList` evaluates to `true`

Comment: I guess there is a serialization problem where on deserialization, instead of returning an Empoyees, an ArrayList is returned. Let me create a test for it and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug on our side. I created a bugreport:

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/6455

The following code should resolve your problem for the time being:

```
public class Main  {

public static void main(String[] args){
    HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    IMap<String,Employees> map = hz.getMap("foo");
    map.put("1", new Employees());

    Employees employees = map.get("1");
    System.out.println(employees);
}

static class Employees extends ArrayList implements DataSerializable {
    @Override
    public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(size());
        for(Object item: this){
            out.writeObject(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        int size = in.readInt();
        for(int k=0;k<size;k++){
            add(in.readObject());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks a lot for acknowledging the issue. I used a wrapper class to wrap around the objects that I need to put into IMaps (as values) used in my product.  Due to legacy code, I cannot introduce a dependency on `DataSerializable` at this moment. However you suggestion is excellent. ! Thank you.